# dataTables not formatted on Page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have recently started working on datatables and have so far with help from some genues in the community been able to get to a point in my code so far. The issue I have is

1: when I refresh my browser, because it takes few seconds to display the datas, the table headings all appears to be merged together

[image: screenshot]

2: Also I am using datatables v1.10.x and i tried using the new APIs like **alertTable.clear().draw();** instead of **dataTable().fnClearTable();** but I am getting **alertTable.clear is not a function**. I noticed changing from dataTable to DataTable seems to have an effect but it still does not work.

Any help will be much appreciated as I am still new to this plugin.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var red=0;
    var orange=0;
    $(document).ready(function (){

    setInterval (function(){
        $.getJSON("ajax/maint1_json.txt", function (pcheckdata){

        <!-- ------------------- Extract all Alerts ---------------------- -->
        if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#alert-table')) {
            $('#alert-table').dataTable({
                "bInfo": false,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "data": pcheckdata.alerts,
                "aaSorting": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
                "columns": [
                    { "mData": "source" },
                    { "mData": "host" },
                    { "mData": "description" },
                    { "mData": "value" }
                ],
                "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                    if ( aData.value == "5" )
                    {
                        $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Red');
                        red++;
                    }
                    else if ( aData.value == "4" )
                    {
                        $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Orange');
                        orange++;
                    }
                },

                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {
                        "targets": [ 0 ],
                        "visible": false,
                        "searchable": false
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": [ 3 ],
                        "mRender": function( data, type, full ) {
                        if (data == "0") {
                            return '<input class="button" type="button" id="ack-action" value="Acknowledge Alert" onclick="<-- call a function to modify value -->;">';
                            }
                            return data;
                        }
                    }
                ],

                <-- if json value is null or empty -->

                'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                    $.ajax ({
                        'dataType': 'json',
                        'type': 'POST',
                        'url': sSource,
                        'data': aoData,
                        'success': fnCallback
                    });
                },

                "fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings ) {
                    $('.alertcount-red').empty().append(red);
                    $('.alertcount-orange').empty().append(orange);
                    red=0;
                    orange=0;
                }
            });

            } else
            {
                $('#alert-table').dataTable().fnClearTable();
                $('#alert-table').dataTable().fnAddData(pcheckdata.alerts);
                $('#alert-table').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
            }

        if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#error-table')) {  

        <!-- ------------------- Extract all Errors ---------------------- -->
            $('#error-table').dataTable({
                "bInfo": false,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "data": pcheckdata.errors,
                "columns": [
                    { data: 'host' },
                    { data: 'description' }
                ],

                'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                    $.ajax ({
                        'dataType': 'json',
                        'type': 'POST',
                        'url': sSource,
                        'data': aoData,
                        'success': fnCallback
                    });
                }
            });
        } else
        {
            $('#error-table').dataTable().fnClearTable();
            $('#error-table').dataTable().fnAddData(pcheckdata.alerts);
            $('#error-table').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
        }

        });
    }, 10000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: anyone able to assist or guide. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for this question, a little bit of reading the API documentation helped me understand the difference between using **DataTables** & **dataTables**. The difference here is one with big G and other with small g. The smaller g returns jquery while big G returns DataTables API.

Comment: ok Chelseawillrecover ...